# How to post a json data and a file using angular js formdata

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I tried sending json data and a single file using angular formdata but its not working. I don't receive json from my server. Here is my code with angularjs

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;
          element.bind('change', function(){
             scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
             });
          });
       }
    };
 }]);

angular
.module('BossApp')
.controller('addresumeCtrl', addresumeCtrl);

function addresumeCtrl ($scope,ngDialog,$http) {

     $scope.resume = {};
     $scope.resume.educations = [];
     $scope.resume.experiences = [];

     $scope.create = function(){
       var uploadUrl = "/user/add-resume";
       var fd = new FormData();
      for(var key in $scope.resume)
         fd.append(key, $scope.resume[key]);
      $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
     headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
     }).then(function (response) {

    }, function (error) {

     });
   };
 }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you solve this? In my case, I just used `$http({method:'POST', url:uploadUrl, ...});`

Comment: I'm wonder why did you use directive? And I couldn't find the code which put your file into form data.